# how to access data in json

Tags: jquery, json

i have a json file like this which i get after doing  `parse`

```
var json = JSON.parse(data)

 {"current_page":1,
"data":[{"id":1,"test_col":"Test one"},{"id":3,"test_col":"Test three"},{"id":4,"test_col":"Updated from post man"},{"id":5,"test_col":"Test five"},{"id":6,"test_col":"Test six"},{"id":7,"test_col":"Test seven"},{"id":8,"test_col":"Test eight"},{"id":9,"test_col":"Test nine"},{"id":10,"test_col":"Test ten"},{"id":11,"test_col":"test eleven"}],
"first_page_url":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test?page=1","from":1,"last_page":2,"last_page_url":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test?page=2","next_page_url":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test?page=2","path":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test","per_page":10,"prev_page_url":null,"to":10,"total":15}
```

i have tried accessing it like this

```
console.log(json.data)
console.log(json.current_page)
```

but i get undefined for both

Comment: Why is there a PHP tag?

Comment: Problem not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/pqdyhm6g/

Comment: @Andreas just remove it...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/wmL3jcav/5/ @04FS

Comment: I figured I'd give him/her a chance if it was "I can do it in either of them". But yes. Agree. @Nick

Comment: @t2355615 logging to console works fine in your fiddle. `$("#show").html(json.data);` throws an error, because you did not include jQuery. And even if you do, `json.data` is an array of objects, you can not directly use that as the HTML content to set for an element, and expect that to create meaningful output.

Answer (score 0):

its working. please check...

```
  var json = 
     {"current_page":1,
    "data":[{"id":1,"test_col":"Test one"},{"id":3,"test_col":"Test three"},{"id":4,"test_col":"Updated from post man"},{"id":5,"test_col":"Test five"},{"id":6,"test_col":"Test six"},{"id":7,"test_col":"Test seven"},{"id":8,"test_col":"Test eight"},{"id":9,"test_col":"Test nine"},{"id":10,"test_col":"Test ten"},{"id":11,"test_col":"test eleven"}],
    "first_page_url":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test?page=1","from":1,"last_page":2,"last_page_url":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test?page=2","next_page_url":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test?page=2","path":"http:\/\/api.changemaker\/api\/test","per_page":10,"prev_page_url":null,"to":10,"total":15}
    console.log(json.data);
```